# What do the values in CertificateSigningRequest.spec.usages mean?

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, x509

When creating a `CertificateSigningRequest` (or `csr` for short) with the Kubernetes Certificate API we can specify "usages". The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#create-certificatesigningrequest) show the following example for creating a `csr` object:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: myuser
spec:
  request: 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
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
  expirationSeconds: 86400  # one day
  usages:
  - client auth
EOF
```

The docs show that many different usages can be set here:

```
>> kubectl explain csr.spec.usages
KIND:     CertificateSigningRequest
VERSION:  certificates.k8s.io/v1

FIELD:    usages <[]string>

DESCRIPTION:
     usages specifies a set of key usages requested in the issued certificate.
     Requests for TLS client certificates typically request: "digital
     signature", "key encipherment", "client auth".

     Requests for TLS serving certificates typically request: "key
     encipherment", "digital signature", "server auth".

     Valid values are:
     "signing", "digital signature", "content commitment", "key encipherment",
     "key agreement", "data encipherment", "cert sign", "crl sign", "encipher
     only", "decipher only", "any", "server auth", "client auth", "code
     signing", "email protection", "s/mime", "ipsec end system", "ipsec tunnel",
     "ipsec user", "timestamping", "ocsp signing", "microsoft sgc", "netscape
     sgc"
```

Why does a TLS client certificate need "digital signature", "key encipherment", "client auth" as usages? What do these individual usage values mean? Which consequences does it have if some or all of these usages are set or not set?

I would also like to understand what the meaning of the other available options is but couldn't find a resource online.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a TLS client certificate need "digital signature", "key encipherment", "client auth" as usages?

It describes the purpose that the certificate created will have (and as you can see there are several ones). This avoids that certificates created for some specific purpose are used improperly.

> What do these individual usage values mean? Which consequences does it
> have if some or all of these usages are set or not set?

You've to specify one. In your example you're creating a Certificate which will be used by someone (likely just your *kubectl*) to authenticate to API Server as a specific User (thus a Client Authentication or `client auth`), other common uses cases are certificates used by Web Server to basically certify they're who they say they are (Server Authentication or `server auth`).

I don't actually know all the values but I'm pretty sure you can find some explanation [online](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/11.0.0/conf_keyusageextensionsandextendedkeyusage_r.html).